# Calculate Abnormal Returns using a for() loop

Tags: r, for-loop

It's a bit complicated! I want to get the Abnormal Return on event-days using Fama-French. The time window is: 250 days just before the event-day.

first, my data.frames:

```
require(quantmod)
require(zoo)

# STOCK DATA.FRAME
BRCM <- as.data.frame(getSymbols.yahoo("BRCM", from="2000-01-01", verbose=F, auto.assign=F))
AAPL <- as.data.frame(getSymbols.yahoo("AAPL", from="2000-01-01", verbose=F, auto.assign=F))
MSFT <- as.data.frame(getSymbols.yahoo("MSFT", from="2000-01-01", verbose=F, auto.assign=F))

BRCM$Company <- c("BRCM")
AAPL$Company <- c("AAPL")
MSFT$Company <- c("MSFT")

BRCM$Return <- Delt(BRCM$BRCM.Adjusted)
AAPL$Return <- Delt(AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted)
MSFT$Return <- Delt(MSFT$MSFT.Adjusted)

colnames(BRCM) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted", "Company", "Return")
colnames(AAPL) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted", "Company", "Return")
colnames(MSFT) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted", "Company", "Return")

data <- rbind(BRCM, AAPL, MSFT)

data$Open <- NULL
data$Close <- NULL
data$High <- NULL
data$Low <- NULL
data$Volume <- NULL
data$Adjusted <- NULL

data$DATE <- row.names(data)

# EVENT DATA.FRAME
COMP <- c("BRCM", "AAPL", "AAPL", "MSFT", "BRCM", "BRCM", "MSFT")
DATE <- c("2003-03-04", "2004-12-01", "2002-12-03", "2008-02-08", "2003-10-10", "2005-12-12", "2003-11-14")

events <- data.frame(COMP, DATE)

events$AR <- paste("")

# FAMA FRENCH DATA.FRAME
date <- data$DATE
Mkt.RF <- sample(c(-2, -1.3, -0.9, -0.5, 0.15, 0.45, 0.95, 1.4, 1.8), size = nrow(data), replace=T)
SMB <- sample(c(-0.54, -0.41, -0.3, -0.21, -0.1, 0.12, 0.23, 0.34, 0.42, 0.6), size = nrow(data), replace= T)
HML <- sample(c(-0.54, -0.41, -0.3, -0.21, -0.1, 0.12, 0.23, 0.34, 0.42, 0.6), size = nrow(data), replace= T)

ff <- data.frame(date, Mkt.RF, SMB, HML)
```

sorry I'm really bad at making those examples.
The only important thing so far is, we've got 3 data.frames

1. data (with all the stock related data)
2. events (with all the event related data)
3. ff (with all the Fama-French related data)

now i want to use a for() loop to calculate the abnormal returns (AR).
There's probably a much easier way to do this, but I came up with this and
I hope there's a genius out there, who understands what i want to do!

```
# create R Objects for loop
companies <- as.vector(unique(events$COMP))
days <- as.vector(unique(data$DATE))
W <- lag(zoo(days), -c(0, 250:1))
ES_list <- vector("list", length = length(companies))


 for(i in 1:length(companies)) {

  data_k <- data[which(data$Company==companies[i]),] # all trading days for each firm
  events_k <- events[which(events$COMP==companies[i]),] # all event days for each firm

 for(j in 1:nrow(events_k)) {
  d = which(days==events_k[j,"DATE"])
  Z = W[d,] # time window assigned to each event-day (250 days)
  Y = data_k[which(is.na(match(data_k$DATE, Z) == F)), "RET"] # all Returns of time window (250days)
  X = cbind(rep(1, ncol(W)), ff[which(is.na(match(ff$DATE, Z) == F), c("Mkt.RF", "SMB", "HML"))]) # explaining variables
  b = (t(X) %x% X)^(-1) %x% t(X) %x% Y # my model to get coefficients to calculate abnormal return (AR)
  events_k[j, AR] = data_k[d, "Return"] -b[1] -b[2:4] %x% ff[d,2:4]
  ES_list[i] = events_k 
  }
}

ES = do.call(rbind, ES_list)
```

I think this loop should work, but it gets me the Error:

```
Error in arr.ind && !is.null(d <- dim(x)) : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

Does Anyone have an idea what this means and how to solve it?

The Output should be events (data.frame) with a column with all the abnormal returns on event days (events$AR).
Thank You

Comment: `Error in nrow(mydf) : object 'mydf' not found`

Comment: I also get errors in this line `W <- lag(zoo(days), -c(0, 250:1))`, condition has length > 1, which results in a zoo series, W, with no columns, so that when you `X = cbind(rep(1, ncol(W))`, I get another error, invalid times argument because `ncol(W)` is NULL. Do you also get these errors?

Comment: Yes, I got an error in this line, when i had some additional packages loaded. It should work if there's only base, quantmod and zoo.

Comment: Looks like you should be using matrix multiplication operator `%*%`, rather than `%x%`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your code fails, but I think I would use the `apply` family of functions rather than `for` loops. Also, I would try time series objects (I guess `quantmod` returns `xts` objects), which should make window selection easier.

Note that I'm using a data frame with the Fama and French daily factors. Ian Gow provides the code [here](http://iangow.wordpress.com/2011/08/07/r-code-to-fetch-fama-french-factor-data/).

The following returns an `xts` object with one column per event. From there you should be able to get any summary stats you'd like. Let me know if I'm too far off (I don't know the larger goal or code).

```
require(quantmod)
require(zoo)

# get data and find returns
tickers <- c("BRCM", "AAPL", "MSFT")
prices <- lapply(tickers, getSymbols, auto.assign=FALSE, from="2000-01-01")
my.ret <- function(x) {
    y <- dailyReturn(x, type="log")
    names(y) <- strsplit(names(x)[1], "\\.")[[1]][1]
    y
}
returns <- lapply(prices, my.ret)
returns <- merge(Reduce(merge, returns), read.zoo(ff_daily_factors), all=FALSE)

# EVENT DATA.FRAME
COMP <- c("BRCM", "AAPL", "AAPL", "MSFT", "BRCM", "BRCM", "MSFT")
DATE <- c("2003-03-04", "2004-12-01", "2002-12-03", "2008-02-08", "2003-10-10", "2005-12-12", "2003-11-14")

# my function to calculate predicted abnormal returns
my.AR <- function(x, tic, day) {
    x$exret <- x[, tic] - x[, "rf"]
    est.beg <- as.Date(day) - 280
    est.end <- as.Date(day) - 30
    model <- lm(exret ~ mktrf + smb + hml +umd, data=window(x, start=est.beg, end=est.end))
    pred.beg <- as.Date(day) - 29
    pred.end <- as.Date(day) + 29
    exret.hat <- predict(model, window(x, start=pred.beg, end=pred.end))
    exret.hat <- zoo(exret.hat, order.by=as.Date(names(exret.hat)))
    x <- merge(x, exret.hat)
    x$exret - x$exret.hat
}
ARs <- Reduce(merge, mapply(my.AR, tic=COMP, day=DATE, MoreArgs=list(x=returns), SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
names(ARs) <- paste0(COMP, DATE)
returns <- merge(returns, ARs)
```

Does this help?

Comment: @ Richard Herron: Thank you for your answer! Your code works perfectly! Just, the output should be a panel exactly like my data.frame "events" with an additional column AR.

Comment: i only changed     pred.beg <- as.Date(day) - 0  and     pred.end <- as.Date(day) + 0 because I need only the abnormal return on the event day.

Comment: Great. In that case you can do an additional merge to combine returns and ARs.

Comment: `merge(returns, ARs)`. I'll add this to the answer.